# 'Not a Certification Authority' while importing self-signed certificate

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I've created a self-signed SSL certificate for local development. When accessing the page, I get a `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. But when I try to import it into Chrome ([chrome://settings/certificates](http://chrome://settings/certificates)), it fails:

> The file contained one certificate, which was not imported:
>
> - mylocalwebapp.dev: Not a Certification Authority

This is the command I've ran to create the certificate:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes \
 -extensions SAN \
 -reqexts SAN  \
 -days 365 \
 -newkey rsa:2048 \
 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key \
 -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt \
 -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:mylocalwebapp.dev'))
```

I've added the SAN-options because as of version 58, Chrome doesn't accept it [without SAN](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/854). It worked on Chrome 57 and it still works on Firefox.

How can I get my self-signed certificate working on Chrome 58 on Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to make sure we're covering our bases... Have you tried the processes outlined here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate

That used to work for me, but as of this morning, after updating to Chrome 58.0.3029.81, I also get the following error in the console for a self-signed cert that used to work on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).
```

EDIT:

I've just had success with one of the methods from the link I referenced above. It completely goes around Chrome because it seems like something has changed with Chrome and it's not working right anymore.

To dump the cert using OpenSSL client (probably not necessary, but in case you want to be very thorough):

```
$ echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect $DOMAIN_TO_FETCH_FROM:443 | sed -ne '/BEGIN CERT/,/END CERT/p' > my-cert
```

To install the dumped cert using `certutil`. If you didn't dump your cert with openssl, replace `my-cert` with whatever filename is appropriate:

```
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n my-cert -i my-cert
```

Check the installation of the cert with `certutil` (if you feel so inclined):

```
$ certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L

# Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
#                                                              SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
#
# my-cert                                                      P,,
```

Completely close and restart Chrome, and maybe you will find success. Worked for me on both 58 and 59-beta.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. It worked on Chrome 57, but as of 58 Chrome doesn't accept my certificate. Since you've got the same problem, you haven't got a solution either?

Comment: Nope, nothing yet. Going down a similar road in Firefox provides a different error that's maybe more informative for me "MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY", maybe there's something to that, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: If you run `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L` do you see your self-signed cert listed? Mine shows up with "CT,C,C", which is the way I think it's supposed to show, but again, I don't know for sure.

Comment: I just tried Chrome Canary Version 59.0.3071.9 (Official Build) dev (64-bit), and still no luck.

Comment: This hasn't helped Chrome yet, but it did make Firefox and curl work:

`sudo cp $CERT_FILE /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ && sudo update-ca-certificates`

Going to try restarting to see if Chrome eventually comes around.

Comment: Haven't used any `certutil` command to get it working before, I'll try if that makes any difference. Firefox works without any problem, even without that command.

Comment: Seems like my last comment didn't actually help Firefox. Just curl. A restart didn't make Chrome any happier.

Comment: I've just got something working that I swear I tried hours ago and didn't work then. The approach I'm taking completely goes around Chrome because something there changed and isn't working right.

To dump the cert: `echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect $DOMAIN_TO_FETCH_FROM:443 | sed -ne '/BEGIN CERT/,/END CERT/p' > my-cert`

To install the dumped cert: `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n my-cert -i my-cert`

Completely close and restart Chrome, and maybe you will find success.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! The last step did the trick. My original key (`/etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key`) is exactly the same as Chrome exports and `openssl s_client` gives me, so I think you can skip that step.

Comment: No luck for me ... I see them listed but still can't add them to chrome

Comment: Working on Chrome 63. I just exported the certificate following the EXPORT part of this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15076602/3194525 and then importing it with `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n my-cert -i my-cert`

Comment: More on this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/linux_cert_management.md